# For-Loop to read and save multiple data files

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to apply the same code to around 600 separate files. I cannot first merge all files, as individual files are already very large. I would like to open file per file, do my data manipulations, save that file, close it and go on to the next file).

My code is the following:

```
#List all files from directory (this works)
files <- list.files("path", pattern="*.TXT")

#Loop over files
for(i in 1:length(files))
{
data[i] <- read.table(files[i], header=TRUE)

data[i] <- merge(data[i], dataset, by.x="ID", all.x=TRUE) #dataset is a file containing IDs for observations I wish to select from each file (it has a variable 'dummy' that equals 1 for each ID i wish to subset)
attach(data[i])
dummy[is.na(dummy)] <- 0

data[i] <- data[i][which(dummy==1),]
write.table(data[i], "PATH/data[i].txt", sep="\t")

rm(list=ls())
}
```

**OUTPUT**
Listing all files from directory works:

```
> print(files)
[1] "2729_1636_1687.TXT" "2729_1688_1739.TXT"
```

The loop does not work:

```
Error in data[i] <- read.table(files[i], header = TRUE) : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

**SOLUTION**

```
for(i in 1:length(files))
{
data <- read.table(files[i], header=TRUE)

data <- merge(data, dataset, by.x="ID", all.x=TRUE) 
dummy[is.na(dummy)] <- 0

data <- data[which(dummy==1),]
write.table(data, paste("PATH/data[",i,"].txt"), sep="\t")

rm(data)
}
```

Comment: Data is a function, but you also need to initialize the variable before you subset it.

Comment: It looks as if `rm(list = ls())` is what is causing you grief here. It removes everything from memory including your `files` vector. Once the loop tries going back on itself it has nothing to iterate through.  Try removing that (and stop attaching your data) and see how that works.

Comment: This may not work as intended: `write.table(data[i], "PATH/data[i].txt", sep="\t")`.  Replace with: `write.table(data[i], paste0("PATH/data[",i,"].txt"), sep="\t")`

Comment: You want something like `data <- read.table(files[i], header=TRUE)` (but since `data` is an R function name, it's better to use a different name for your data frame). `data` rather than `data[i]`. You just need a single data frame object for each iteration of the loop, right?

Comment: Thank you all, I added the solution above.